# Arduino + GPRS m95 not responding

Tags: arduino, gsm, gprs

Im trying to communicate with a Quectel M95 GSM module but im just receiving squares as a response. The module is supposed to auto baud but it seems that it is not working.

The code that im using i took it from [David Barnes question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729444/arduino-read-at-commands-from-quectel-m95-gsm-module):

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPin 10
#define txPin 11

SoftwareSerial mySerial(rxPin,txPin); // RX, TX

void setup(){

  pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Arduino serial initialized!");
  delay(10);

  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Software serial initialized!");
  delay(10);
}

void loop(){
  issueCommand("AT");
  readSerial();
  delay(3*1000);

  while(true){
    readSerial();
  }
}

void issueCommand(char* msg){
  mySerial.println(msg);
  Serial.print(msg);
  delay(10);
}

void readSerial(){
  while (mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Im getting the following as an answer from the GSM:

[image: Response]

What can it be? I have tried everything :/ Even if i try it using Windows Hyperterminal i dont recieve anything.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Rather than rely on the autobaud feature, have you tried selecting different baud rates?

Comment: I checked changing the baud rate in the Arduino terminal. I tried to change it from the hyper-terminal but it seems that doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the same code by switching RX and TX values. I tried your sample and it worked successfully. Maybe you connected RX TX pins wrong.